# C# Algo Splitting a list of integers into three lists with similar sum

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, math, split

I'm currently working on an algorithm that will split a list of integers but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a list of integers that I will have to split into 3 lists, and the sum of all those lists should be as similar as possible. I started on a demo project with this list:

```cs
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

In this case, the result should be :

list1 = {1,4};

list2 = {3,2};

list3 = {5};

And here is my code :

```cs
public static List<List<int>> ProvideLists(List<int> originalList)
{
    List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>> { new List<int>(), new List<int>(), new List<int>() };
    var listToParse = originalList;
    while (listToParse.Count > 0)
    {
        var smalestList = result.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Sum() < b.Sum() ? a : b);
        var biggestList = result.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Sum() > b.Sum() ? a : b);
        var diffSmallBig = biggestList.Sum() - smalestList.Sum();
        var closestNumber = listToParse.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x - diffSmallBig)).First();
        listToParse.Remove(closestNumber);
        smalestList.Add(closestNumber);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Currently this code return :

list1 = {3};

list2 = {5,2};

list3 = {4,1};

If anyone has any clue to help me :)

Comment: Hint: the sums must be close to a third of the total. Then you have to solve two approximate subset sum problems, which are notoriously difficult !

Comment: This is indeed an NP-Hard problem. Here's a paper about solving it: https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/09/Papers/096.pdf Also see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20multiway%20number,the%20Identical%2Dmachines%20scheduling%20problem)

Comment: how about the broot force approach and sort all possible combinations of the 3 lists by closeness to 1/3 of it's sum?